# How can I prevent chromium from spawning so many threads?

Tags: linux, debian, chrome

We have a Raspberry Pi (with Raspbian/Debian 8/Jessie) set up to run chromium in kiosk mode as a status monitor for our local network. It is set up to load one page from a server on our network; the page has a tiny bit of Javascript that simply reloads the page every 30 seconds.

It works great for about 2 hours then crashes with an "aw snap!" error page.

I've been doing some digging & figured out how to turn on logging for chromium. This revealed the following error message:

```
[246:254:0117/113914:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(118)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

A little googling led me to [this page](http://rudametw.github.io/blog/posts/2014.04.10/not-enough-threads.html) which suggests that the problem is that the system does not have enough threads available. I checked the limit on the system using `ulimit -a` abd found that `max user processes` is equal to 7336.

Next I set up a simple script to log the number of chromium processes using `ps -elfT | grep chrom | wc -l` and found that chromium is slowly spawning more threads, crashing when the number of threads reaches 222 (up from a low of around 50).

It's not definitive proof that this is the problem, but the steadily increasing number of threads does look like a problem, which leads to my question:

**How can I prevent chromium from constantly spawning new threads?**

Comment: Not using `chrome`/`chromium` i guess. That is the best way to prevent it from opening so many threads. lol - https://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html - Despite the joke it is at chrome's heart to do that way, and some tweaks like `--memory-model=low`(that enable low resource profile) can no longer be configured.